# Reading a byte stream file

Tags: c, file-read

I have a C code for a application written for a POS device by someone else.
There are text files which are been updated using a TCP socket. 
But the contents of those files cannot be read by using a normal text file reader(notepad / word). When I open the file it shows like following image:
[image: File opened in notepad]

But in the code it reads with no mistakes. It reads using a `memcpy`.
That code part is shown bellow.

```
stat("farestructure.txt", &st_t);
fSize = st_t.st_size;

fd = open("farestructure.txt",O_RDWR);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
readSize = read(fd, tempBuffer, fSize);
close(fd);
if(readSize!=fSize)
{
    printf("File Read Error\n");
    return -1;
}

k = 0;

memcpy(&(fs.fareStructureVersion), tempBuffer+k, 4);
k=k+4;
memcpy(fs.commenceDatetime, tempBuffer+k, 7);
k=k+7;
memcpy(fs.expiryDatetime, tempBuffer+k, 7);
k=k+7;
memcpy(&(fs.sectionCount), tempBuffer+k, 2);
k=k+2;
memcpy(&(fs.consessionTypeID1), tempBuffer+k, 1);
k=k+1;
```

Is this in byte format?
How can I read this contents in the file?

Comment: *"But the contents of those files cannot be read by using a normal txt file reader"* - so... why do you think it is a text file ?? If those targets of copying are anything other than zero-terminated char arrays, I can assure you that is not a "text" file. Can't really say, as you inconveniently chose to omit the type of `fs` from the post. Regarding your last question. You have the code to read it right there. Isn't that sufficient (quality and platform dependence notwithstanding) ?

Comment: I want to get to know the format of the file contents. I want to replace the contents of the file. For that I want to know where the specific data is written in the file.

Comment: @Thushantha.Srimal Since file is written in _binary format_ so, content is coded. You need to know in advance that _which byte having what meaning?_ e.g. in your above code there is line `memcpy(&(fs.fareStructureVersion), tempBuffer+k, 4);`. So the programmer knowing in advance that _structure version is coded in first 4 bytes_. Like wise you can read and change the values. But as   I said earlier. You need to know the format of _content written in the file, in advance_.

Comment: This question is off-topic, I am afraid. You seem to have the code for reading the binary file, so it's unclear what else you need. If you want to check the contents of binary file, use a hex editor (e.g. [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), which is a freeware hex editor with a bunch of useful tools like calculation of CRCs, hashes, or viewing running programs as binary data, or viewing raw disk data directly). Visual Studio also has a simple integrated binary editor, if you're on Windows.

Comment: @cse yes that is correct. Thats my problem. Lets say like this. Now I know the "structure version" is coded in first 4 bytes. Lets say it says the number 5. I want to change it to 6 and write into that file. How can I do that?